# Failing to log in to App Store Connect whilst using produce

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm using `produce` to create an app in App Store connect but after being prompt for my Apple ID, I got the following output signaling a failure:

> {"responseId"=>"f1988c04-b3a7-4eca-b4b3-8afc8542478f", "resultCode"=>1200, "resultString"=>"You are not allowed to perform this operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support", "userString"=>"You are not allowed to perform this operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support", "creationTimestamp"=>"2018-11-26T22:07:05Z", "protocolVersion"=>"QH65B2", "userLocale"=>"en_US", "requestUrl"=>"https://developer.apple.com/services-account/QH65B2/account/ios/identifiers/addAppId.action", "httpCode"=>200}

I think this has something to do with two factor authentication, but I am not sure how I should proceed. Anyone have had this experience before?

Comment: Run the command with `--verbose` and post more of your output please, whole output if possible. Can you do the same action in the web UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Apple Developer Program Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) and [App Store Connect Role Permissions](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve5f9a89d7). To create an app you need to have:

- the permission of either **Admin** or **App Manager** in App Store Connect
- the permission of either **Agent** or **Admin** in Apple Developer Program (to register and configure the App ID)

This error means the user you've logged in as has a different role:

- You may be *Finance*, *Dev*, *Marketing*, *Sales*, or *Customer Support* in App Store Connect
- You may be *Member* in Apple Developer Program

My guess is you are an App Store Connect dev user and need to be promoted to App Manager.

Comment: Can you print the output with the `--verbose` command? It's possible it's not using the account that you think it's using

Comment: The output summary shows I'm using the correct username with the app manager role.

Also shows the following outputs:

1. `Loading session from '/Users/kelvinlau/.fastlane/spaceship/kelvin.lau@X.com/cookie`. 


2. `Loading session from environment variable`


3. `Couldn't find team with ID '<random sequence of letters`.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have access to the team ID being used when you try to create the app. You can debug by creating a client: run `bundle console`, then type `require 'spaceship'`, then `client = Spaceship.login`. Type your Apple ID to login. Then if you type `client.teams.map { |team| team['teamId'] }` you'll see a list of all the team IDs you have access to.

Comment: My team IDs do not match the team ID visible from the Xcode project.

Comment: In addition to App Manager, produce also needs authorization to create an App on the Dev center. 

After using an account with both Admin level role in both ATS and the dev center, I was able to get produce working.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to get it working! I will add the info from your comment to my answer.